# Always Get Data as String from Excel file using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, types, exceldatareader

There is a cell in my Excel file containing this number: `5892101102012990`
and other cells containing mixed data (also strings)
I get this cell's data like this :

```
var filestream = File.Open(@"D:\111XLS\File.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(filestream);    
while (reader.Read())
{
    var intt = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);                      
    var v1 = reader.GetValue(intt);
    var v2 = reader.GetValue(intt + 3);

    listBox1.Items.Add(v1 ?? ""); 
    listBox2.Items.Add(v2 ?? "");
}
```

When it gets to that cell in return I have this : `5.89210110201299E+15`
If I change the cell format in Excel file to `Special`(Excel assumes it's a Zip-code) it will return exact number but editing the Excel file is out of options.

I'm aware that I can get the data using `reader.GetDouble(intt);` but because of mixed content this will cause more trouble.

Any advice on some sort of option to tell `ExcelDataReader` to not converting `5892101102012990` to this `5.89210110201299E+15`?

Comment: is there a way to convert the FileStream's cells to string on the fly and then feed it to ExcelDataReader to fix the problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that i have to answer my own question here after 14 views.

i just tried to convert the `5.89210110201299E+15` to a normal number using this :

```
Decimal.Parse("5.89210110201299E+15", NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

i don't know if i'm about to ran into a problem later on .

i'm still looking forward to a better solution.
any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use `GetFieldType(int index)` function like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var intt = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);                      
    var v1 = reader.GetValue(intt);
    var v2 = reader.GetValue(intt + 3);

    var fieldType1 = reader.GetFieldType(intt);
    var fieldType2 = reader.GetFieldType(intt + 3);

    var value1 = v1 == null ? null: Convert.ChangeType(v1, fieldType1);
    var value2 = v2 == null ? null: Convert.ChangeType(v2, fieldType2);

    listBox1.Items.Add(value1?.ToString() ?? string.Empty); 
    listBox2.Items.Add(value2?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
}
```

And if you want to use a Format-String before adding it to your list, use a code like this:

```
var valueString1 = value1?.TsString();
if (value1 != null && fieldType1 == typeof(double))
{
    valueString1 = ((double)value1).ToString("####");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
var number = 5892101102012990D;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("F0"));
```

Output:

```
5.89210110201299E+15
5892101102012990
```

Your results sound like the implicit behaviour of `object.ToString()`, so this could be a formatting concern. If you want the same output as is displayed in Excel, you may be interested to format the value using the [ExcelNumberFormat](https://github.com/andersnm/ExcelNumberFormat) library

Comment: can you explain more about "F0" ? is there any reference on ToString("XX") ? (i mean the "XX" Part)

Comment: [The Fixed-Point ("F") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString)